# Is a set consisting of the terms of a convergent sequence in $\mathscr C_b(A, \mathbb R^m)$ closed in $\mathscr C_b(A, \mathbb R^m)$?

Tags: general-topology, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

This is a follow-up to my previous question:

> Let $f_k$ be a convergent sequence in $\mathscr C_b(A, \mathbb R^m)$.
>
> Is $S=\{f_k \mid k = 1,2,\ldots\}$ closed in $\mathscr C_b(A, \mathbb R^m)$?

Obviously, $S$ is closed iff. the limit function (call it $f$) lies in S. But is the given information sufficient to answer the question conclusively?

Comment: No, you simply don't know whether the limit is a term of the sequence unless it's somewhere stated.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, thanks. I'm somewhat surprised that this problem is an open-ended question, given that it is from a chapter on uniform convergence and the space of continuous functions.

Comment: Perhaps the expected answer is "In general, it's not closed."